# Trying to read binary file to connect with a user on my website

Tags: c#, serialization, webforms, binaryfiles

I have been able to write&read before from a bin file with my C# application (webforms). After I have made some changes, I can still write but can't read more than one User.

I used the debugger. The foreach loop counts only 1 user from Serialization.Users even though there is 2 users in the file. It is a static List. It worked before. I can't figure what I did wrong.

````
        ``` 
        format = new BinaryFormatter();
        Users = new List<User>();

        try
        {
            flux = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        }
        catch
        { 
            Users.Add(new User("root", "root123", "email@abc.com", "Administrator"));
            Users.Add(new User("user", "user123", "email@abc.com", "User"));
            Save(path);
        }
        finally
        {
            Users = (List<User>)format.Deserialize(flux);
            if (flux != null)
               flux.Close();
        } 

        foreach (User account in Serialization.Users)
        {
            if (account.Username == username.Text && account.Password == password.Text)
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        ```
````

I should be able to login with the second user, but as I mentionned, the foreach loop stops after 1 iteration and returns false. I don't understand why.

Comment: why do you read in the finally block? you should move content of your finally block into the try block, right after flux = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); and in finally you only do if(flux != null) flux.Close

Comment: I use the finally block because in my catch block, I write before reading again so instead of pasting new FileStream twice (both in try and catch block), I only write it once at the end of the catch block and in finally, deserialize.

Comment: Please re-read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. There is no need to show all *interesting* things your actual code does - just important but reproducible parts. Like showing code that presumably writes 2 users.

Comment: you should not use the try catch in this way, do not rely on exception to understand if file does not exist and save it, instead, in the try block iyou can check if file exists or not and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what went wrong in my code.
 The problem was not my try/catch but when the new user created his account. After signing in properly and going back to the homepage by disconnecting, **Page_Load()** does not read my binary file again because I forgot to deserialize there.